# How to add filtering to columns in webgrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

Q: How can I add filtering (like that of excel - see screenshot) to an existing asp.net-mvc3 webgrid?

Is there a JQuery solution to apply to each column or would this fall into the category of holistic custom third party grid controls?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for Ajax, but I think the best option is to use third party grid. I prefer Telerik MVC collection. There is excellent Grid control. [Here is link](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx)